# Address is not incrementing?

Tags: c

It is said that,in c,b++; is equal to b=b+1; if this is the fact test++ in my code why generate a compile time error.
test+1 is working well but test++ is not working.but why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   char test[80]="This is a test";
   int a=13;
   for(;a>=0;a--)
  {
        printf("%c",*(test++);
  }
}
```

Comment: Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: Which _compiler time error_? Something like **error: lvalue required as increment operand**. I think it is self-explicative...

Comment: @LPs: Probably something like "expression `test` is not an lvalue".

Comment: Why do you expect an array behave like a pointer?

Comment: @EOF yes, It was a joke. I was editing ;)

Comment: Once you read the actual error message, [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896637/lvalue-required) and its answers will probably be fairly informative.

Comment: Well, the mismatched brackets won't help:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `++` and `--` operators are not defined for arrays.

`v++;` would be the same as `v = v + 1;`. Assumed `v` was typed an array this would imply assigning to an array, which is not defined.

Comment: Oh boy, oh boy ... - so what's wrong here, please? *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

```
char test[80] = "This is a test";
char *p = test;

for(int a = 0; a < 14; a++)
{
    printf("%c", *(p++));
}
```

Comment: And how does this answer the question?

Comment: @alk It provides a possible solution. Other answers cover what's wrong.

Comment: The question is "*but why?*", not "but how?". I do not want to say additionally providing a solution is wrong, but without giving a reason why the initial approach doesn't work, there is missing an essential part.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one thing, `b++` is *not* the same as `b=b+1`.
But even if it were -- I think you'll find you get a similar error if you try `test = test + 1`.

Comment: I feel this would have better suited as a comment.