# operator keyword and operator overloading simulation

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I understand that we can apply increment and decrement on intrinsic data types such as:

```
int a;

a++;
a--;
```

...etc.

However, in the following codes, if I omit the `&` in the line `operator int& ( ) { return value; }`, I will get a compile error.  Please explain how and why using `&` makes the increment possible here:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {

public:
   int value;
   operator int& ( ) { return value; }

};


int main ( ) {
    Foo p;
    p.value = 10;

    p++;

    std::cout << p <<  std::endl;

    std::cin.get ( );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function definition:

```
operator int&() { return value; }
```

Allows a conversion from your class `Foo` to a reference to int.

This line:

```
p++;
```

Cannot increment `p` as type `Foo` as the class does not have `operator++` implemented. However it is able to convert p to a reference to `int` via a call to `operator int&()` which returns a reference to `value` within the particular instance of `Foo`. The reference to `value` is of type `int` which can be incremented using `++`. So the code then increments `value` in-place.

As to the distinction between returning an in and a reference to int, the following code shows the behaviour you mention is not distinct to the conversion oeprator:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : m_value(0)
    {
    }

    int getCopy() { return m_value; }
    int& getRef() { return m_value; }
private:
    int m_value;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;

    // Works
    f.getRef()++;

    // Does not work on g++ with 'error: lvalue required as increment operand`
    f.getCopy()++;
}
```

The reason you cannot do an increment when the conversion operator returns `int` rather than `int&` is that the increment operation requires an lvalue, i.e. something that can be the target of an assignment. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353384/l-value-required-error) for more detail.

Comment: Isn't this line " operator int ( ) { return value; } " converts class Foo to an int any way? although not a reference to int, but int nevertheless, so the p++ should work, but it is not.